# Вылезающий div сверху после 2-х секунд пребывания на сайте

Tags: javascript, html, css

Подскажите, как сделать, чтобы div после открытия сайта, спустя 2 секунды появился по центру сайта?

Нужен простенький код, который показывает этот div, без закрытия и прочих ненужностей. Желательно с написанной мной анимацией CSS. То бишь код просто сделает ее активной спустя 2 секунды.

Comment: Спасибо, вопрос решен.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

```
/*HTML*/
<div id="window">Окно</div>

/*CSS*/
#window {display:none}

/*JS*/
$(document).ready(function() {
   setTimeout(function() {
      $('#window').show();
     }, 2000);
})
```

JQUERY думаю сможете подключить. И стили тоже напишите свои для этого дива.

Answer (score 0):

**Вылезающий**

> То бишь код просто сделает ее активной спустя 2 секунды.

```
setTimeout(function(){
   var $div = document.getElementById('#id'); // как угодно получаем элемент
   $div.setAttribute('class', 'animated-class'); // присваиваем необходимый css-класс
}, 2000);
```

---

Ответ из комментария [@Etki](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/16095/etki).